# Solve a given trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the following equation:
$$\sin x + \sin \left( x + \frac{7\pi}{24} \right) = \frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt 2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt 6 + \sqrt 2}{4}$$

So far, I found out that $\frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt 2}}{2} = \sin \frac{\pi}{8}$ and $\frac{\sqrt 6 + \sqrt 2}{4} = \sin \frac{7\pi}{12}$.

Thank you!

Comment: Try using $\sin A + \sin B = 2 \sin \left( \frac{a+b}{2}\right) \cos \left( \frac{a-b}{2}\right) $.

Comment: Yes in both sides

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Expand the second $\sin$, to write your

equation as

$$A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)=1$$

or

$$\cos(x+\alpha)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

> second approach

the equation is

$$
\sin(x)+\sin(x+\frac{7\pi}{24})=$$

$$\sin( \frac{\pi}{8})+\sin(\frac{7\pi}{12}  )=$$

$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})+\sin\left(\pi-(\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{7\pi}{24})\right)=$$

$$\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})+\sin(\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{7\pi}{24})$$

Comment: How does your second approach lead to a solution?

Comment: @AnuragA By the first.

Comment: That is exactly the point, then how is it second approach?

Comment: @AnuragA the first gives all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sin x +\sin (x+7\pi /24).$

We have $$f(\pi /8)=\sin (\pi /8)+\sin (\pi /8+7\pi /24)=\sin (\pi /8)+\sin (10\pi /24)=$$ $$=\sin (\pi /8)+\sin (14\pi /24)=\sin (\pi /8)+\sin (7\pi /12)$$ which is the RHS of your equation.

Now $f'(x)=\cos x +\cos (x+7\pi /24).$

So $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $-\pi /2-7\pi /48\leq x\leq \pi /2-7\pi /48.$

And $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing for $\pi/2 -7\pi /48\leq x< 3\pi/2-7\pi /48.$

So there are at most 2 values of $x$ in $[-\pi/2-7\pi /48,\;\; 3\pi /2-7\pi /48)$ for which $f(x)=f(\pi /8).$ And there do exist 2 values: $x=\pi /8$ and $x=\pi-\pi /8=7\pi /8.$

So $x=\pi /8 +2\pi n$ or $x=7\pi /8+2\pi n$ for some (any) $n\in \mathbb Z.$